# How to make multiple parallel concurrent requests with Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, concurrency, resque

I am currently developing a Rails application which takes a long list of links as input, scrapes them using a background worker (Resque), then serves the results to the user. However, in some cases, there are numerous URLs and I would like to be able to make multiple requests in parallel / concurrency such that it would take much less time, rather than waiting for one request to complete to a page, scraping it, and moving on to the next one.

Is there a way to do this in heroku/rails? Where might I find more information?

I've come across resque-pool but I'm not sure whether it would solve this issue and/or how to implement. I've also read about using different types of servers to run rails in order to make concurrency possible, but don't know how to modify my current situation to take advantage of this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Resque`. Use `Sidekiq` instead.

`Resque` runs in a single-threaded process, meaning the workers run synchronously, while `Sidekiq` runs in a multithreaded process, meaning the workers run asynchronously/simutaneously in different threads.

Make sure you assign a URL to scrape per worker. It's no use if one worker scrape multiple URLs.

With Sidekiq, you can pass the link to a worker, e.g.

```
LINKS = [...]
LINKS.each do |link|
  ScrapeWoker.perform_async(link)
end
```

The `perform_async` doesn't actually execute the job right away. Instead, the link is just put in a queue in redis along with the worker class, and so on, and later (could be milliseconds later) workers are assigned to execute each job in queue in its own thread by running the `perform` instance method in ScrapeWorker. `Sidekiq` will make sure to retry again if exception occur during execution of a worker.

PS: You don't have pass a link to the worker. You can store the links to a table and then pass the `id`s of the records to workers.

[More info about `sidekiq`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki)

Comment: I'll take a look at Sidekiq. The latter part about one URL per worker makes sense to me, but I'm a bit confused on the process of how I know when all the URLs are done being scraped? Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I I am confused still. So I would call the above Scrapeworker.perform_async(link) , and then I would call Scrapeworker.perform  , and then it would execute all jobs in the queue from the async at the same time in different threads? And it would pause/process there until done solving the issue of when the URLs are done being scraped?

Comment: Not quite right. You don't call the `perform` instance method directly. Sidekiq  will read the queue, wait for a thread in a thread pool to be available, and ask the thread to run `perform` instance method of a worker that is specified in the queue. Your job is to call `perform_async` class method that puts the job to the queue.

Comment: I see - but this doesn't answer how I know when the job is complete so I can return to the user ?

Comment: You can do anything in your `perform` method, such as trigger status in your table, call other methods, call other workers, etc. at the end of your `perform` method (this means all previous expressions have passed). You can to this because the return value of `perform` method is not used anyway.

Comment: This would only tell me when a single link was done and not all of them though - no?

Comment: You can use sidekiq batches to do something when all job you specified completed (see https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches).

Comment: This would have solved my problem exactly the right way, except it requires paying $1k/yr . Instead I basically added a parameter to the very last job in the queue to mark it complete and it works - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two lines to your code will also let you wait until the last job is complete before proceeding:

- this line ensures that your program waits for at least one job is enqueued before checking that all jobs are completed as to avoid misinterpreting an unfilled queue as the completion of all jobs

`sleep(0.2) until Sidekiq::Queue.new.size > 0 || Sidekiq::Workers.new.size > 0`

- this line ensures your program waits till all jobs are done

`sleep(0.5) until Sidekiq::Workers.new.size == 0 && Sidekiq::Queue.new.size == 0`